# Сохранение данных при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте. Есть страница, где заполняется тест (checbox и text поля), нужно при случайное перезагрузке страницы или при отключении интернета загружать страницу, где уже будут отмечены те поля, которые отмечал пользователь. А если пользователь прошёл тест (нажал submit), то при следующем заходе надо снова подгружать чистый тест. Через что проще всего это реализовать?

Comment: [Сессии](http://phpfaq.ru/sessions)

Comment: @Даниил Я не знаю как в сессии записать то, что отметил пользователь, т.к. все данные я получаю только после отправки формы.

Comment: [Ссылка](http://pgwjs.com/pgwcookie/)  При клики на элемент сохраняй значение в сессию или куки. 
 [Ссылка](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При заполнении формы можно сохранять данные о заполненных полях в localStorage или в cookie. И при каждом открытии формы проверять localStorage или cookie на наличие соответствующих данных: если они имеются - соответственно применять их к полям формы. При успешной отправке формы данные в localStorage или в cookie должны очищаться.

Comment: Как сохранять в localStorage сохранять "онлайн" я понимаю, а как в куки записывать без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: @BornToNight с помощью javascript. Или скачайте jquery.cookie.js и с помощью неё (тоже самое, если вы используеюе jquery)

Comment: @user190134 спасибо, почитаю, попробую!